# getItem() returns null with SQLContainer after selection in grid object, but the row exists

Tags: java, mysql, vaadin

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I simply want to select an item from a SQLContainer which is being displayed as a grid object using Vaadin. I basically want to fill a form with the content of the selected item so that I can edit the item before saving it (standard CRUD).

The building blocks:

```
        String q4text = "select a.name, aty.name "
                + "from asset a "
                + "join assettype aty on a.assettype_id = aty.id";
        FreeformQuery q4 = new FreeformQuery(q4text, connectionPool, "a.id");
        q4.setDelegate(new AssetQueryDelegate());
        assetContainer = new SQLContainer(q4);
```

This is my SQLContainer with the FreeformQuery. In the snippet you see "a.id" as the primary key. I tried "id" and "ID" in the past. The result is the same. This container is accessible through a DatabaseHelper and I bind it to a grid object.

```
SQLContainer assetContainer = db.getAssetContainer();
grid.setContainerDataSource(assetContainer);
```

Now, I try to fill the form with the following code snippet

```
    grid.addSelectionListener(event -> {
        if (event.getSelected().isEmpty()) {
            form.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            Set<Object> selected = event.getSelected();
            Item item = assetContainer.getItem(new Object[] {selected});
            form.setCustomer(item);
        }
    });
```

When I run the web app, I can see the grid contents and I can sort. The problem arises when I select a row and I call the getItem function. I always get null. I've tried with assetContainer.getItem(selected) as well. If I run it through the debugger I indeed see the rowId (equivalent of a.Id) in the selected Set. If I print the assetContainer to the screen, I also see the contents and I can see the item I would expect to select, yet the result is always null. Am I using the wrong function? Is there a problem with the primary key in the FreeformQuery? I designed the table with MYSQL and there are two primary keys with the name id in the asset and the assettype tables (of course, I want asset.id to be the primary key of this query, not assettype.id).

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was easier than I expected (after spending almost one day trying things).

```
    grid.addSelectionListener(event -> {
        if (event.getSelected().isEmpty()) {
            form.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            Item item = assetContainer.getItem(event.getSelected().iterator().next());
            form.setCustomer(item);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i see.  getItem() expects an ItemId as Parameter. you transfered a Set of ItemIds before ;)